# Controlling Constraint of Cell Item from TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a TableViewController with dynamic cells containing 3 labels and an imageView inside it. I created it in a Storyboard. It looks like this...

```
      - Label1
 oImg - Label2
      - Label3
```

And, Label2 is vertically centered to the imageView (call it constraint-A); and the other labels are aligned to Label2, too.

What I am trying to do is, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in TableViewController, check if Label3 is empty, move Label2 down and Label1 keeping the constraint set before (so also move down).

As first option, I tried connecting the constraint-A to TableViewController,but as it it is TableViewCell, I am unable to connect the constraint outlet to TableViewController.

Then, I tried manually moving them down, but weirdly it's only affecting one row (first one without Label3) whereas rest of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` works okay..

```
cell.Label2.frame.origin.y += 5
cell.Label1.frame.origin.y += 5
```

What is the appropriate way of achieving this? (So I can either control the constraint-A or move Label2 manually and Label1 follows)

Comment: It depends on your constraint. You can make **Constraint Outlet** to *YourCusstomCell Class* . In cellForRow, you can check if your Datasource for Label3 is Empty, you change constraint on this method.
I guess you need make all labels and image outlet to make a constraint.

Comment: And it depends on your requirement that your row's height is fixed or not, and your label is 1 line or multiple line.

Comment: set Label3 Number of Line 0 and remove vertically centered to the imageView , when text is empty your label2 automatically down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create IBOutlet property for y-cord constraint of label1 and label2 and then you change "your property name".constraint = "some value" rather than changing the frame y-cord.

Comment: So create 2 more labels for Label1 and Label2 and hide/show them accordingly? I can't create an outlet from a UILabel in TableViewCell to TableViewController

Comment: Don't create new labels, create their y-cord constraint property only.

Comment: Create a custom class say CustomCell inheriting from UItableViewCell and connect to the TableViewCell which is in UItableViewController. Now you can create a property inside CustomCell and use inside cellforrowatIndexpath function of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]

```
 //set above image 2
  cell.constLbl.constant = -(cell.lbl3.frame.size.height / 2 - 10); // this obj below img 1
cell.constLbl3Top.constant = cell.lbl3.frame.size.height / 2; // this obj below img 2
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer. ranjit's answer was a quicker way but +1 for your explanations